# Multilevel logistic regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I would like to use logistic regression for classification task. I have a data set of news product description and their titles. I also have a hierarchical tree of the products categories and subcategories. The hierarchical tree is of depth 6. Of course each product will have multiple labels from the child node all the way up

I know how to use logistic regression for single level, but what I don't know is how I can use the classifier from level1 in level2 until I get to a leaf node.

I prefer python, but I can use Matlab and Java.